# How to create a tar file (tar.gz) file with a specific directory tree

Tags: directory, compression, tar

I'm trying to backup a directory tree which has this structure:

```
/home/joe/projects/goodie/binary_program
/home/joe/projects/goodie/image.png
/home/joe/projects/goodie/sound.ogg
/home/joe/projects/goodie/license.txt
```

I want to create the archive with the following structure:

```
goodie-2015_04_09-15_34/binary_program
goodie-2015_04_09-15_34/image.png
goodie-2015_04_09-15_34/sound.ogg
goodie-2015_04_09-15_34/license.txt
```

I know how to create the date/time stamp label, but I don't know how to actually create the tree structure inside of the tar file..any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU tar has a --transform option which runs sed on file names (or file paths) prior to putting them into the archive.

```
source=/home/joe/projects/goodie
name=goodie-2015_04_09-15_34

tar cvzf $name.tar.gz $source/* --transform "s@^$source@$name@"
```